# Configurable product and its associated product creation using soap api documentation is not in magento api guide.any idea?

Tags: magento, soap, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a configurable product and its associated product using magento soap api.Product created successfully but configurable product linking with associated product is not working properly guys any idea? This is my code

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient('https://sample.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

// If some stuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('username', 'Password');

// get attribute set
$attributeSets = $client->catalogProductAttributeSetList($session);
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
print_r($attributeSet);
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple',72, 'product_sku0002', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description',
    'additional_attributes' => array(
        'single_data' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'color',
                'value' => 'Red', // Id or label of color, attribute that will be used to configure product
            )
        ),
    ),
));
var_dump ($result);
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'configurable',72, 'Configurable_product_sku0001', array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => 'Confihurable Product name',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description',
    'associated_skus' => array('product_sku0002'),
    'price_changes' => array(
        array(
            'color' => array(
                'Red' => '0'
            )
        ),
    ),
));
var_dump ($result);
?>
```

Comment: Is that code show anny error in log file.

Comment: No error in log file. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: can you put your code in try.....catche block, to debug is there any error.

Comment: I put it in try.......catch... no exception message.. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: Can reindexing magento from admin.

Comment: Reindexed and cache removed but same result.Configurable product and simple product created but linking with these two is not working. @DhirenVasoya

Comment: now i got a exception Caught exception: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'key' property @DhirenVasoya

Comment: thanks  @DhirenVasoya for your suggessions at last i found answer in http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine using this method follow the link
http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/